Vitest - ReferenceError: location is not defined
I'm trying to set up vitest for a Vue application that was recently converted from Vue 2 to Vue 3.  I'm getting the following error, and have been unsuccessful in determining what the problem is.  Here is the error I'm getting:
FAIL  tests/unit/components/MyComponent.spec.js [ tests/unit/components/MyComponent.spec.js ]
ReferenceError: location is not defined
  Module.createWebHashHistory node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs:850:5
  src/router/index.js:42:12
     40|
     41| const router = createRouter({
     42|   history: createWebHashHistory(),
       |            ^
     43|   routes,
     44|   scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
  src/components/MyComponent.vue:1:1

Apparently, createWebHashHistory() references something called location, but I can't tell where I should be definining it.
I realize this isn't much to go on, but at this point I'm just looking for pointers on how to debug this, or things to check.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Do you even need the Hash history nowadays? Can't you use createWebHistory?

The problem turned out to be that the component under test was doing import router from "@/router", so that it could push a new location using router.push().  Changing that to using this.$router.push() and removing the import fixed the problem.

OP solved the problem by using this.$router.push().
